# is it possible to start looking at configuration that starts with a particular string

Tags: lua

I am using lua to parse through several xml files, these files are over 1000 lines but I am only looking to run my lua commands that exist between lines that start with `<certificate>` and `</certificate>`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can either use some XML library or you use a string pattern to extracts anything between `<certificate>` and `<\certificate>`.

You'll need to use a capture in that pattern. Read

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1